# Sorting List container using template function

Tags: c++, list, function, templates, sorting

I have a header, which consists of different template functions

```
#include <cmath>

template<class T>
bool lessThan(T x, T y) {

    return (x < y);

}

template<class T>
bool greaterThan(T x, T y) {

    return (x > y);

}
```

A class

```
class Point2D {
public:
    Point2D(int x, int y);
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
    double distFrOrigin;
```

In my driver class, I have an STL List of Point2D: `list<Point2D> p2dL`. How do I sort `p2dL` using the template functions `lessThan` and `greaterThan` in my header? i.e. Sort the list based on `x` or `y` value.

**EDIT**: And so, based on Anton's comment, I came up with this:

```
bool Point2D::operator<(Point2D p2d) {

    if (this->x < p2d.x || this->y < p2d.y
            || this->distFrOrigin < p2d.distFrOrigin) {

        return true;

    }

    else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

Did I do it correctly?

Comment: You will need to implement the < operator for your class, otherwise the compiler does not know how to deal with the comparison.

Comment: There is no "correct" way to order two 2D points. You have to decide which arbitrary choice suits your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, all three major templates can be exposed using *just* an `operator <()` so long as you enforce strict ordering:

```
template<class T>
bool lessThan(const T& x, const T& y) 
{
    return (x < y);
}

template<class T>
bool greaterThan(const T& x, const T& y) 
{
   return (y < x);
}

template<class T>
bool equals(const T& x, const T& y) 
{
   return !(x < y) || (y < x));
}
```

Next, your class must implement `operator <()` to compare a `*this` against a parameter. A sample appears below:

```
class Point2D {
public:
    Point2D(int x, int y);

    // sample that orders based on X primary, and Y if X's are equal.
    bool operator <(const Point2D& other) const
    {
        return (x < other.x || (x == other.x && y < other.y));
    }

protected:
    int x;
    int y;
    double distFrOrigin;
};
```

Lastly. sort your list like so:

```
// sort ascending
std::sort(p2dl.begin(), p2dl.end(), lessThan<Point2D>);

// sort descending
std::sort(p2dl.begin(), p2dl.end(), greaterThan<Point2D>);
```

Or as Juan pointed out, use the list-sort directly:

```
p2dl.sort(lessThan<Point2D>);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `std::list::sort` method directly, instead of `std::sort`:

```
p2dl.sort(lessThan<Point2D>);
```

But you have to implement `lessThan` and `greaterThan` or similar functions in terms of Point types. For example:

```
template<class T>
bool greaterThan(const T& p1, const T& p2) {

    return (p1.x > p2.y);

}
```

Note that the above comparison function is just an example, you have to decide how to implement less-than and greater-than with 2D points.

For completeness, here's a lexicographical comparison using `std::tie`:

```
template<class T>
bool greaterThan(const T& p1, const T& p2) 
{
    return std::tie(p1.x, p1.y) > std::tie(p2.x, p2.y);
}
```